# javascript error when using azure mobile service scripts

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-mobile-services

I'm attempting to filter some results using azure mobile service scripts but i'm getting this error in the log.The parameters I pass to  this function are also shown.

ERROR
Error in script '/table/Restaurant.read.js'. Error: Invalid callback options passed to 'query'. Callback options must be an object with at least one 'success' or 'error' property of type 'function' or a systemProperties property of type 'Array'.
    [external code]
    at read (:7:11)
    at :1:6
    [external code]

Here's my code

```
function read(query, user, request) {
  var location=request.parameters.Location;
  var category=request.parameters.Category;
  console.log("location is"+location);
   console.log("category is"+category);
   var sql="SELECT * from restaurant where Location=? AND Category=?";
   mssql.query(sql,[location],[category],{success:function(results){request.respond(statusCodes.Ok,results);}});

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters to the query need to be passed as a single array, instead of an array per parameter. If you change your query from

```
mssql.query(sql, [location], [category], {
    success: function(results) { request.respond(statusCodes.Ok, results); }
});
```

to

```
mssql.query(sql, [location, category], {
    success: function(results) { request.respond(statusCodes.OK, results); }
});
```

It should work. As a side note, you should use `statusCodes.OK` instead of `statusCodes.Ok` ("OK" all in caps).